# post-apocalyptic novel (farmers & a Russian airman)

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

Need help finding a book, for a friend (read about 20 years ago)

his text:

It's one of yer postapocalpytic numbers ... farming family in their own little valley are shielded from the worst of it though they could see the flashes and tops of the clouds over the hills, but once the food and fuel (and ammunition...) starts to run out, and the radio broadcasts peter out, they go off in the pickup truck to hunt for supplies in the nearest town, leaving the eldest daughter behind to tend to the animals for the day or two they expect to be gone. They never return, and we're then left seeing the rest of the story unfold through her eyes, as someone who appears to be a Russian airman comes over the hill in a rather bad state... various drama then ensues, and at the end of it, one of them (can't even remember which) takes off over the horizon on the remaining tractor with the last of the fuel, presumably having never heard of biodiesel. It was another one of these where the author had died and someone else stepped in to finish off the final chapter from his notes. Any clues, anyone?

ps: will add more info if/when possible.

Comment: This sounds like a mis-remembered version of *Z for Zachariah*, which was recently asked about [in this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45112/teenage-girl-in-life-sustaining-valley-on-poisoned-earth-visited-by-another-surv/45117#45117).

Comment: You are indeed correct!