# British TV show from 1970s set after a nuclear war

Tags: story-identification, tv

I vaguely remember watching a British TV show (possibly only one show, but maybe a series), where nuclear war has occurred.  A family (maybe in Wales) has survived because they live in a remote valley, where the explosion/fallout missed them because the valley was steep sided.

I think the premise was that the family couldn't leave the valley due to, what they thought was, the radioactive fallout elsewhere.  The final part of the show was one of the characters walking out the valley.

(I only remember this because there was a scene where one of the main female characters was nude in the bath, and showed breasts (I was about 7 or 8 at the time, hence why I remember it)).

I want to say there was an actress in it called something like Pippa Hinchley.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be [*Survivors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivors_(1975_TV_series)) but that was a plague not a nuclear way apocalypse.

Comment: Funny how certain things stand out in ones memory... ;)

Comment: @FreeMan there was an unexpected outburst of interest in a fitness TV show in France in the 80's. We (teenager boys) were watching it religiously because the last part was the fitness teachers taking a shower. Yes, a shower - the show was in the morning on Sundays if memory serves me right. This is an indication of how much has changed in France during one generation (good and bad things) - my teenage+ children are amazed by that and look at such TV shows as if they were from another planet .

Comment: @FreeMan (cont'd) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlGgiElosFQ shows the last moments of the exercise (debriefing) and then here we are... It is NSFW but coooome oooon... it is an official clip from the French national institute of audiovisual (INA)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This sounds like an episode of "Play for Today" entitled *[Z for Zachariah](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088439/)*. It was shown in 1984, but possibly the date has drifted a little in the OP's memory.

As in the question, it dealt with life after a nuclear war, where eventually just two characters are left, surviving in a Welsh valley protected by its unusual meteorological conditions. The main character, Ann Burden, was indeed played by Pippa Hinchley.

An entertaining summary at [telly301](https://telly301.rssing.com/chan-51468426/all_p6.html#c51468426a118?zx=813) gives these details:

> An adaptation of Robert C. O'Brien's posthumous 1974 novel of the same
> name (albeit with the US swapped for Wales), *Z for Zachariah* aired
> under the Play for Today banner during the long running anthology's
> final year. The screenplay was adapted by Anthony Garner who was most
> commonly found in the director's chair and would later go on to direct
> episodes of Auf Wiedersehein, Pet and Soldier, Soldier...
>
> *Z for Zachariah* received just one airing in February 1984 on a Tuesday
> evening at 9.35pm with the play running to just under two hours.
> Although no repeats were forthcoming, the play received constant
> exposure to a generation of British schoolchildren as O'Brien's novel
> formed part of the curriculum at the time, so teachers were keen to
> plonk pupils down in front of this for two hours of additional
> learning - most of the pupils who watched the play at school recall
> feeling depressed by the narrative, but tickled pink by **the sudden
> bursts of nudity**.

Comment: Great find.. well done

Comment: I saw the play when it was broadcast, and I've read the original novel it was based on. As far as I recall, the girl was basically the lone survivor.  No two families, except maybe in flashback before the war.  And then a man in a radiation suit comes to the valley.

Comment: @Pete Yes, I think you're right. One family was left, but this soon got whittled down to one survivor, who is then visited by the man in the radiation suit

Comment: Book is the ur-answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45112/teenage-girl-in-life-sustaining-valley-on-poisoned-earth-visited-by-another-surv, but this is not a duplicate since it's looking for the tv film.