Book about teen girl living in a town by herself (with her dog) as everyone died of radiation poisoning
This was a book that I read a few years ago. It was formatted as diary entries written by a teenage girl where she lives in a town by herself because everyone else died as a result of some form of radiation poisoning. As long as she doesn't leave the town it's safe because it's located in some natural enclave surrounded by mountains. She also owns a dog
A man arrives in a hazmat suit along with a wagon, he believes that the town is deserted (because the girl hid herself away before she could be seen) and is ecstatic about the finding a place with no radiation. The man gets sloppy and dives into the only irradiated water source in the mountain. The girl reveals herself after he gets really sick--brings him home and nurses him back to health for a few chapters.
Man tries to force himself on the girl after he recovers from the radiation and the rest of the book is a cat-and-mouse chase between her and the man. Eventually the girl outsmarts him, takes the man's hazmat suit and supply wagon and leaves the town.
There was a pretty bad movie adaptation of the book thats basically the same plot just instead of just the man and girl as the only characters, they add in another man making it a love triangle romance thing. There's a lot more little details I remember but they don't seem that important.
The cover of the book--I think, was either a close up shot of the mask / hood of a hazmat suit with a figure reflected in the goggles. Or a closeup of a girl's face with a figure reflected in the eye(s). Not entirely sure.

Is it this: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/45112/59154

If you're trying to get people to ID your story, it's rarely a good idea to purposely withhold information.

Hi Kim and welcome to the SFF Stack Exchange. Your description closely matches the book Z for Zachariah. If this is the book please let us know and we will mark this as a duplicate.

Posted an answer, since I hate having questions where we know the answer showing no answer.

As per Teenage girl in life-sustaining valley on poisoned Earth visited by another survivor, this is likely Z for Zachariah by Robert C. O'Brien.


Ann Burden is a teenage girl who believes she is the last survivor of a nuclear war. Since her family's disappearance on a search expedition, she has lived alone on her farm in a small valley spared from radiation poisoning. A year after the war, a stranger in a radiation-proof suit approaches her valley. Afraid he might be dangerous, Ann hides in a cave and does not warn the man when he mistakenly bathes in a radioactive stream. When he falls ill, her fear of being alone forever leads her to reveal herself to help him. She discovers that the stranger is John Loomis, a chemist who helped design a prototype radiation-proof "safe-suit" at an underground lab near Ithaca, New York. Ann moves him into her house and fantasizes about eventually marrying him.
As Loomis becomes more ill and delirious, he has traumatic flashbacks to the underground lab, and talks of how he shot his coworker, Edward, who tried to take the safe-suit to find his family. Though troubled by this revelation, Ann continues to nurse him through his illness and keeps secret her knowledge of Edward's death. As Loomis recovers, Ann is taken aback when he begins criticizing her farming and giving her orders. He forbids her to touch the safe-suit. He orders her to plant wheat and beets to preserve seed stock, and though she acknowledges this is sensible, his explanation that they have to plan "as if this valley is the whole world and we are starting a colony," makes her uneasy. Her uneasiness increases when she asks if he was ever married, and he grabs her hand roughly. He demands to know why she asked and refuses to let go of her until she answers, pulling her off balance until she falls and inadvertently hits his face. He rebukes her for this and does not speak of the incident again. One night soon afterwards, she awakes to hear Loomis in her room. When he attempts to rape her, she flees to the cave again.

Indeed, the movie adaptation added a love triangle.

Perceiving their mutual attraction, John awkwardly gives Ann consent to pursue a romantic relationship with Caleb, but belies his grief and anger in losing Ann through his remarks. Shortly thereafter, following a celebratory dinner, a heavily intoxicated John tells Ann he loves her before passing out in a bedroom in Ann's home. After failing to wake John, seeming to want his affection, Ann joins Caleb in the adjoining bathroom, where the two engage in sexual activity.
Further tensions arise between Caleb and John following the sexual encounter. The two men finish the water-wheel, moving it and its wooden flume into place atop the waterfall. Encumbered by the bulky radiation suit, Caleb slips twice during his rope-assisted climb up the mossy cliffside. During the second slip, the two men silently lock eyes, both holding the rope, while Caleb teeters on the cliff's edge.


BBC also did an adaptation in 1984, set in Wales, for the "Play for today" program.  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088439/
